# Disposing HttpResponse in custom IHttpResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, idisposable

Although I don't care about implementing Disposable for this work. However, I want to take input from folks at SO on how do they implement Disposable when the value is in use by IHttp handlers.

The story is: I have some custom build IHttpResult classes that I am currently using it for API project in Webapi2 framework.

I have one IHttpResult sub class called OKFileDownloadResult that basically read stream contents or a content from the file location and send that file to client.

Here is the code that I have :

```
  var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            StreamContent streamContent = null;

            if (Content == null)
            {
                streamContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(MapPath(LocalPath)));
            }
            else
            {
                streamContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Content));
            }

            response.Content = streamContent;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentType);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = DownloadFileName,

            };
 return response;
```

Here I am returning the response as a last thing in my api action.

However, the question that I have for you that if I use like

using (response = HttpResponse... ) { }

I get the following error, which is understandable.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'.

The question that I have is do I really need to worry about any dispose for MemoryStream, StreamContent or HttpResposneMessage?

Or should I have just leave this task to .Net GC?

Comment: If you're going to pass an `IDisposable` around, you can't dispose of it yourself. I would, however, **absolutely** dispose of that `File.OpenRead` call if you can -- you're leaving open a heavy resource for the GC to come around and get.

Comment: @Cory
 Anything I can do with  MemoryStream, StreamContent or HttpResposneMessage?

Comment: Yes you definitely should dispose your stream instances. You cannot call Dispose on your HttpResponseMessage instance inside your HttpHandler method, as you have already proved.

Comment: @sh1rts doing so throws this: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.